# pass id value to ajax page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass id value to ajax.rmvfile value echoed in this psge.I cant pass this to delete_emp_file.php page.

```
echo '<img src="image/delete1.png" id=".$ef." width="10" height="10" title="Remove" onclick="javascript:myFunction('.$fet['ef_id'].');">';
```

my script code

```
      <script>
       function myFunction(id)
       {   
       alert(id);
       var  rmvfile=id;
      //alert(rmvfile);
      $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'hrms/delete_emp_file.php',
      data:{rmvfile: rmvfile},
      success:function(msg){
      if (msg.length> 0) {
      alert(msg); 
     }
    }
    });
  }
</script>
```

delete_emp_file.php

```
  echo $s=$_POST['rmvfile'];
  include "config.php";
  $echeck="delete from employee_file where ef_id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";
  $echk=mysql_query($echeck);
  $ecount=mysql_num_rows($echk);
  if($ecount>='1')
  {
    echo "file deleted";
 }
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Missing single quotes on the <img>`id` (or double quotes, same story).

Comment: rmvfile is not send to next page. but alert is displayed with correct value

Comment: If you open up the developer tools (e.g. on Chrome or Firefox) you will find more detailed information about the reason why your request fails (turn on the network tab, failing requests usually show in red, you can click on it and inspect). Also, if the code in ``delete_emp_file.php`` is actual live code, then it is vulnerable to SQL injection: see this post on [so](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/870769)

Comment: how to turn on network tag

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined trail.php?eid=1:95
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Connection timed out) http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4fylv9t/n1763/fs15/tct/pct/ftb
4Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined trail.php?eid=1:95
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS http://www.consultville.com/hrms/trail.php?eid=1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Connection timed out)

Comment: Then jQuery (`$`) is missing

Answer (score -1):

You need to add single quotes around the javascript parameter.

Otherwise, javascript parser will consider it as keyword or number.

Corrected code:

```
echo '<img src="image/delete1.png" id=".$ef." width="10" height="10" title="Remove" onclick="javascript:myFunction(\''.$fet['ef_id'].'\');">';
```

Comment: And why you think `$fet['ef_id']` is not numeric?